# Testing DB2 order in java

Tags: java, junit, db2, collation

I'm currently working with DB2 and when I use query with order such as

`SELECT pers.FIRST_NAME FROM PERSON_NAME as pers order by pers.FIRST_NAME;`

I got result

```
Amanda
Any
BannersBroker
BANBRCustomer30
Bob
Bruce
Chack
Christoper
Chuck
Customer
Customer1
Danielle
Eileen
First
First
Frida
Grady
Heath
Jack
John
Jude
Magdeline
MIIPECustomer01
MIIPECustomer02
Olive
Paul
Pay
Recipient1
Require
Rina
Robin
Sean
TestPartner1
TestPartner2
Theodore
Tom
Tomy
Tony
Tory
User
Zane
```

And collations settings for the database is:

```
 Database territory                                      = US
 Database code page                                      = 1208
 Database code set                                       = UTF-8
 Database country/region code                            = 1
 Database collating sequence                             = SYSTEM_1252
 Alternate collating sequence              (ALT_COLLATE) =
 Number compatibility                                    = OFF
 Varchar2 compatibility                                  = OFF
 Date compatibility                                      = OFF
 Database page size                                      = 4096
```

I suppose that DB2 uses some specific algorithms to make this ordering.

The question is how to test such ordering using java? Is there any libraries which can do such string comparisons?

PS: I tried Collator from JDK 6 and ICU4J with different settings and it didn't help.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to test here?  Currently, it looks like the standard comparison operations for Strings would work fine (String implements Comparable).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SET OPTION SRTSEQ (and possibly LANGID) in the SQL reference for your edition of DB2?  (LUW, z/OS, or IBM i)